# Coordinate offset in linear PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have a linear PDE that is not quite traditional of the form $$ F_{x}(x+y,y) - F_{y}(x+y,y) = 0$$ with $F(x+0,0) = f(x).$

I have tried using the method of characteristics in the standard way but it doesn't seem to apply to the present problem. Is this solvable by classical means such as with the method of characteristics and not merely guessing?

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by classical means after a change of coordinates. Setting $u=x+y$, $v=y$, the PDE becomes
$$
F_x(u, v) - F_y(u,v) = 0
$$
with $$
\begin{aligned}
F_x &= F_u u_x + F_v v_x = F_u \\
F_y &= F_u u_y + F_v v_y = F_u + F_v
\end{aligned}
$$
according to the chain rule. Thus, we end up with $-F_v(u,v) = 0$, which can be solved straightforwardly as $F(u,v) = g(u)$ for some arbitrary function $g$. Along the boundary $y=0$, we therefore have $F(x,0) = g(x)$, while we must have $F(x,0) = f(x)$ according to the problem statement. This gives us $g = f$. Finally, the solution reads $$F(u,v) = f(u) \, ,$$ or equivalently, $F(x+y, y) = f(x+y)$.

---

Note: The boundary condition $F(x+0,0) = f(x)$ along $y=0$ is equivalent to the boundary condition $F(u,v) = f(u)$ along $(u,v)=(x,0)$ as written above, which in turn is the same as imposing $F(u,v) = f(u-v)$ along $(u,v)=(x,0)$, with identical final result.

Comment: @JSRSM2 Answer updated, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\partial_x[F](u,v)=\partial_u F \partial_x u+\partial_v F\partial_x v$$
Similarly
$$\partial_y[F](u,v)=\partial_u F \partial_y u+\partial_v F\partial_y v$$
Using $u=x+y, v=y$
$$\partial_x [F](x+y,y)=\partial_{x+y} [F](x+y,y)$$
$$\partial_y [F](x+y,y)=\partial_{x+y} [F](x+y,y)+\partial_y F$$
So your equation is simply
$$-\partial_y[F](u,y)=0$$
Which hopefully you know how to solve...

Comment: What's the meaning of bracketing in $[f]$?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Just differential operator notation. Much in the same vein as how many write the Fourier transform, e.g
$$\mathcal{F}[f](\omega)$$

Comment: OK. Because you use it sometimes and not other times so I was wondering what you were trying to distinguish (if you were)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Apologies, my own sloppiness. I'll clarify.

Comment: This is somewhat ambiguous to me with respect to the notation I used. Are you...saying...$F = f$? Because I used the lower case version $f$ as a boundary condition and you seem to be using it as the solution itself from the start of the problem.

Comment: Whoops, yes it is supposed to be capitalized.

Comment: Thank you. I think something might be off again where you used $x$ instead of $u$. If I substitute $u = x + y,$ what exactly does it mean to take $\partial_{u-y}$?

Comment: For the first identity, is $u$ being assumed as a function of $x$?

Comment: No, this works for general $u=u(x,y)$.

Comment: Would you be able to list the solution so that I can verify whether I derived the correct result?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the last result should be $-\partial_y[F](x,y)$ instead of $-\partial_y[F](x+y,y)$? It seems as though one might need to keep $x + y$ as $u$.

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking. You are correct.